# Moved to new server, all pages work EXCEPT home page (page not found)

Tags: 404-error, migration

I've got the opposite problem a lot of people can when switching servers. All the pages work fine, EXCEPT the home page, which is generating a 404. It's just the blog URL by itself (mysite.com/blogfolder/). Wordpress is installed in a folder in the site root, and worked fine at the old host. htaccess is all what it is supposed to be for this kind of installation. What could cause this??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a static page as homepage, make sure that the page which you were using as static homepage actually exists.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186902/virtualhost-sets-the-url-as-abc-com-subdirectory/40187170#40187170

Have a look at this. It's fairly the same scenario.

Comment: It's not a static page, it's the Latest Posts. And, this was working fine at the previous host.

Comment: Did you try rebuilding the Permalinks ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after Ubuntu Upgrade 16.04 to 18.04, and it was solved by pressing "Purge Caches" in /wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_objectcache

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Ensure that you have the right URL for Wordpress & Site Address in Settings > General
2. Save permalinks in Settings > Permalinks
3. Update the 'Your Homepage displays' in Settings > Readin